# How to prevent action exection once onactionexecuting returning something in mvc-4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created following custom filter and made it attached to a controller as a data annotation. But on action executing if returning some thing then why it execute the action.

```
class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session == null && ctx.Session["currOrder"] != null)
        {
            var result = new JsonResult();
            int[] data = { 1 };
            result.Data = data; /* json data */
            filterContext.Result = result;
            return;
            // return JavaScript("window.location = '" + Url.Action("Index", "Home") + "'");

            //@Url.Action("Search","Controller")

            //ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        return;
    }
}

[Authorize]
[SessionExpireFilterAttribute]
public ActionResult OrderDetails(int index)
{
    if (index == 1)
    {
        return PartialView("_OrderDetails");
    }
    else if (index == 2)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GetUserDetails");
    }
}
```

Comment: on ajax request i want to make it like if session out then return some json set in the onaction executing and on the client side i check onsuccess function of value is 1 then redirect to some page.

Answer (score 0):

To start with check your condition statement. I can't see how you are getting on to the code

Session can not be Null and and a session element cannot have a value at the same time. Should that be an "Or"

```
if (ctx.Session == null || ctx.Session["currOrder"] != null)
```